# POSTGRESQL JOIN not working

Tags: postgresql, join

Running the following...

```sql
SELECT
      a.allocation_date, a.trade_account, a.trade_broker, a.account,
      a.custodian, a.book, a.symbol, a.side,
      SUM(a.quantity)::integer,
      SUM(a.quantity*a.price) / SUM(a.quantity) AS price
    FROM backoffice.allocations a
    inner join symdb.products.product s
    on (symbol=products)
    WHERE a.allocation_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-12-30'
    GROUP BY
      a.allocation_date, a.trade_account, a.trade_broker, a.account,
      a.custodian, a.book, a.symbol, a.side
    ORDER BY
      a.allocation_date, a.trade_account, a.trade_broker, a.account,
      a.custodian, a.book, a.symbol, a.side;
```

...is throwing...

> SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: "symdb.products.product"

The `INNER JOIN` part is what I can't get to work. How do I fix it?

Comment: Are these tables in different databases?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51786826/4709762), Laurenz isn't the most verbose fellow, but it's the correct answer. You need need to use FDWs or move the tables into the same DB to join

Comment: If you need to do that a lot, I highly recommend to use schemas, rather than database to separate tables.

Comment: @JoeW no, it's in the same database.

Comment: If both tables are in the same db, why you are not referencing `symdb` also for allocations? paths seem not to be the same

Comment: If everything is in the same database, then `symdb.products.product` should (probably) be `products.product`

Answer (score 0):

If you do have dots in your schema name, this wouldn't be very good practice as postgres expects the input to be schemaname.tablename so now its getting extra arguements.